# Shadows in Android using Unity 5

Tags: unity

The point lights in my scene cast shadows when it's in the editor mode but the light passes through walls in the build or play mode.
I checked the quality settings and set it to hard and soft shadows for all quality settings but that didn't fix it.
It does work when I increase the quality when I build it for Standalone but not when I build for Android.
I've removed the dx11 option in the PC/Mac Standalone settings.
I've changed both forward and deferred rendering options.
I'm testing it on a Moto G 1st Gen [XT 1033].

Answer (score 1):

My camera was too far from the scene. Cranked up the shadow distance in the quality settings and it works fine now.